# Use Proxy with username,password in python

Tags: python, authentication, curl, proxy, urllib2

Hai I want to use private proxy in python. Please help me to add username,password of proxy in my current Python script.I know there is few lines to add to get in run successfully.

```
data = urllib.urlencode(values) 
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": httpproxy})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req,data)
page = response.read()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Outdated, but I found a site which might resolve this problem.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/523016-using-xmlrpc-with-authenticated-proxy-server/

The relevent code:
    import base64
    import urllib
    from urllib import unquote, splittype, splithost
    import xmlrpclib

```
class UrllibTransport(xmlrpclib.Transport):
    def set_proxy(self, proxy):
        self.proxyurl = proxy

    def request(self, host, handler, request_body, verbose=0):
        type, r_type = splittype(self.proxyurl)
        phost, XXX = splithost(r_type)

        puser_pass = None
        if '@' in phost:
            user_pass, phost = phost.split('@', 1)
            if ':' in user_pass:
                user, password = user_pass.split(':', 1)
                puser_pass = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (unquote(user),
                                                unquote(password))).strip()

        urlopener = urllib.FancyURLopener({'http':'http://%s'%phost})
        if not puser_pass:
            urlopener.addheaders = [('User-agent', self.user_agent)]
        else:
            urlopener.addheaders = [('User-agent', self.user_agent),
                                    ('Proxy-authorization', 'Basic ' + puser_pass) ]

        host = unquote(host)
        f = urlopener.open("http://%s%s"%(host,handler), request_body)

        self.verbose = verbose 
        return self.parse_response(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxy = "http://proxy_user:proxy_passwd@my.authenticated.proxy.server:8080"

    p = UrllibTransport()
    p.set_proxy(proxy)
```

It creates a urllib2 transport class that includes authentication.

Comment: This reciepe is for `urrlib`, not `urrlib2`, which is more functional. In `urrlib2` you don't have to implement `user-agent` and stuff handling by hand. The only reason I know for `urllib` usage nowdays is urllib.urlencode, missed in `urllib2`

Answer (score 0):

What is value of your `httpproxy` variable? Did you try

```
httpproxy = 'http://username:password@proxyurl:proxyport'
```

By the way, `urrlib2` seamlessly [handles `http_proxy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#index-1) environment variable for proxy configuration and `no_proxy` for proxy exemptions. For example for *nix platforms following code should work:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyurl:proxyport
```